# Multiple rows transpose to one row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access project and I want to make a report from a table. I am not pretty sure if this can be done.

The following is the source table

```
Name    Fruits     Count
Jorge   Apple       4
Jorge   Mango       3
Jorge   Pears       4
Jorge   Pineapple   6
James   Apple       8
James   Mango       1
James   Pears       4
James   Pineapple   6
```

And I want a result like this in a continuous form

```
Name    Apple   Mango   Pears   Pineapple
Jorge     4       3      4         6
James     8       1      4         6
```

Any way an SQL can do this?

Comment: Use the [Crosstab Query Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8). It creates a query as in Jörgen's answer, and has the advantage that you don't have to hardcode the fruit names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
TRANSFORM sum(MyTable.count) AS noOfCount
SELECT MyTable.name
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.name
PIVOT MyTable.fruits;
```

Comment: Wow! This is more dynamic. Thank you @Jorgen R.

Comment: If a solution works for you, then please mark as answered.

Comment: anybody can help me how to mark this as answered? I honesty don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In MS Access, this looks like:

```
select name,
       sum(iif(fruit = "Apple", 1, 0)) as apple,
       sum(iif(fruit = "Mango", 1, 0)) as mango,
       sum(iif(fruit = "Pear", 1, 0)) as pear,
       sum(iif(fruit = "Pineapple", 1, 0)) as pineapple
from t
group by name,
```